# cycli fails to connect a docker neo4j database

Tags: docker, neo4j, graphenedb

I have set up a docker neo4j image:

```
2017-11-02 03:29:49.000+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.2.5 ========
2017-11-02 03:29:49.037+0000 INFO  Starting...
2017-11-02 03:29:50.527+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
2017-11-02 03:29:54.338+0000 INFO  Started.
2017-11-02 03:29:55.744+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
```

The port mapping is:

```
7473/tcp    localhost:32770
7474/tcp    localhost:32769
7687/tcp    localhost:32768
```

I am able to connect the browser via `http://localhost:32769/browser/`

Now I want to access it by `cycli`, but failed:

```
Jimmys-MBP:scripts jimmy$ cycli -u neo4j -p xxxxx -h localhost -P 32769
 ______     __  __     ______     __         __
/\  ___\   /\ \_\ \   /\  ___\   /\ \       /\ \
\ \ \____  \ \____ \  \ \ \____  \ \ \____  \ \ \
 \ \_____\  \/\_____\  \ \_____\  \ \_____\  \ \_\
  \/_____/   \/_____/   \/_____/   \/_____/   \/_/
Cycli version: 0.7.6
Neo4j version: 3.2.5
Bug reports: https://github.com/nicolewhite/cycli/issues

> match(n) return n;
Unable to connect to localhost on port 7687 - is the server running?
```

Why is it still looking for docker port 7687?

Comment: How exactly do you run your docker image? I.e. which ports are exposed? Cycli afaik uses the bolt port, not the http one.

Comment: I use kitematic to run the official neo4j image. Could you give me an example to your connection command? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely that source of the problem is following configuration parameter in neo4j.conf

```
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687
```

Due to the fact you redirect port 7687 using docker port mapping

```
7687/tcp    localhost:32768
```

you should also modify bove config to make sure neo4j advertise port 32768 instead default port 7687.

Accorng to the [documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/docker/) that could be achieved environment variable when staring docker conatiner with following command

```
sudo docker run -d --publish=32769:7474 --publish=32768:32768 --env=NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/neo4jadmin  --env=NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address=0.0.0.0:32768 --name cycli_test_neo4j neo4j
```

However, there is this [bug](https://github.com/nicolewhite/cycli/issues/51) in cycli which needs to be resolved for all this to work.